# GVRReticlePointer not working properly with onClick Events

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I followed this tutorial and done everything that was mentioned, everything looked and worked fine except the reticle point expands and contracts when I gaze upon the cube but the click event does not trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for random teleport is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class ReticleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void RandomlyTeleport()
    {
        Debug.Log("reached here");
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(
            GetRandomCoordinate(), Random.Range(0.5f, 2), GetRandomCoordinate());
    }


    private float GetRandomCoordinate()
    {
        var coordinate = Random.Range(-7,7);
        while( coordinate > -1.5 && coordinate < 1.5)
        {
            coordinate = Random.Range(-5,5);
        }
        return coordinate;
    }
}
```

These are screenshots
[image: ReticlePointer Inspector panel]
[image: Cube's inspector panel]

Update :

It turns out that the same thing is happening when I bring up the scene that comes premade with SDK HelloVR, although the hexagon(the only interactive thing in the scene) changes color when I gaze at it, nothing else happens when I click it. So, this is not a problem with what I made but the inherent problem of unity or the SDK